# How to get wordforms in sphinx?

Tags: sphinx, morphological-analysis

How i can get all morphology forms of the word?

For example, searching keyword is:
`runner`

Result should be:
`run,running ... etc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually don't need one. Use a stemmer, which can do the reverse. ie it removes the "ending", so that matching works, rather than trying to figure out all the possible endings.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming

ie use morphology, rather than worforms. 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-morphology